# TypeScript: Deserializing multiple types from a single object

Tags: typescript

I have a JSON array of serialized objects that each have a `type` field.  I'm trying to deserialize them but can't get TS to play along:

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=46#code/C4TwDgpgBAzhBOBLAhgG0QLwgEwIJQF4oBvKUSALigHJdqAaKZABXgHswqZgkA7AcygBfANwAoAMapkMGFHzExUZVDABXAEboJZcBAK1q4lVAlte3eGonA28ABTZkwZFwQp0WPAEoSQsf5i5NBwSGiYOABChCS6lDSRDFAarBxcPIgCwuJSMnLRiibqWog6wYTUiUoqZhY81rYOTi5uYZ5RvsT+gbXcptKyALLIYDGkuIzRomJiAGZqvDaI5lDYEKEeEfYb4V4A8hoAVhA2rZte+AA+sO67HSTVyr3AUADSA3JEuUMjANo77WwB2ONgAdMEALrGFS8CAAdzeH22t0BwJOwG84iEQA)

```js
type serializedA = { type: 'A', aProp: string };
class A {
    public type = 'A';
    constructor(data: serializedA) {}
}

type serializedB = { type: 'B', bProp: string };
class B {
    public type = 'B'
    constructor(data: serializedB) {}
}

const classMap = { A, B };

function deserialize(serializedObject: serializedA | serializedB) {
    const Klass = classMap[serializedObject.type];
    new Klass(serializedObject);
}
```

The issue is that last line.  TS doesn't know that `Klass` and `serializedObject` are now either both `A` or both `B`, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell it that.

Comment: The issue is that the construct signature of `Klass` is `new (serializedA & serlializedB) => A | B` which reduces to `new (never) => A | B` since the type `{type: 'A' & 'B', 
aProp: string, bProp: string}` must be empty. This is definitely annoying since you know better, but you have to either use a type assertion or write a series of tests that narrow the type to its individual possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

For production grade decoding libraries, take a look at following:

- [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts)
- [runtypes](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes)
- [class-transformers](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)

we are using io-ts extensively. You can refer it [here](https://github.com/tmtsoftware/esw-ts/blob/master/lib/src/clients/location/models/Connection.ts)

Comment: I would second `io-ts` as an excellent option for this. We also use it exclusively

Answer (score 0):

```
type serializedA = { type: 'A', aProp: string };
class A {
    public type='A';
    constructor(data: serializedA) {}
}

type serializedB = { type: 'B', bProp: string };
class B {
    public type ='B'
    constructor(data: serializedB) {}
}

const classMap = { A, B };

function deserialize(serializedObject: serializedA | serializedB) {
    if(serializedObject.type === "A"){
        let Klass = classMap[serializedObject.type]
        return new Klass(serializedObject);
    } else {
        let Klass = classMap[serializedObject.type]
        return new Klass(serializedObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid that ;)  There are about 50 different classes and I don't like writing super verbose code just to make TS happy